# Solving a Difficult 2nd-Order Linear ODE with Variable Coefficients

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform

I would like to solve the following differential equation:

$$y''(x)+\left[a^2-\frac{b(b+1)}{x^2}\right]y(x)=0$$

where $a>0$ and $b=0,1,2,...$

I tried to solve this equation by applying a Laplace transform to both sides but this yielded another differential equation that I was unable to solve:

$$(s^2+a^2)Y''(s)+4sY'(s)+[2-b(b+1)]Y(s)=0$$

where $Y(s)=\mathscr{L}_x[y(x)](s)$. Does anybody know how to solve either the original or the transformed equation?

Comment: What boundary conditions are you interested in?

Comment: The boundary conditions are not important. I'm looking for a solution with two arbitrary constants.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By introducing $f(x)$ which is related to $y(x)$ via $$y(x)= x^{1/2} f(x)$$ your ODE is transformed into
$$x^2 f''(x) + x f'(x) + 
\left[a^2 x^2 - \left(b + \frac12\right)^2\right] f(x)=0.$$

This is [Bessel's differential equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function) with the general solution
$$ f(x) = c_1 J_{b+1/2}(a x) + c_2 Y_{b+1/2}(a x).$$